# Why this trigger won't work?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I have a simple postgreSQL table

```
Flight (id, pilot, copilot)
```

and I want to add a trigger to avoid creating records having pilot = co-pilot because of course one single person can't do both :D

I tried this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION controllaPiloti() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (SELECT pilot FROM flight WHERE pilot = new.pilot AND copilot = new.pilot)
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Pilot and copilot must be different!';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE TRIGGER checkPiloti
BEFORE INSERT ON flight FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE controllaPiloti();
```

but it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Define 'Doesn't work'

Comment: You trigger checks data that is already in the database, and you run it before the current data is inserted. This could not work. Read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: doesn't work means I can still create a record having the same value on pilot and copilot columns. Also tried removing EXISTS but no result

Comment: tried also as condition IF (comandante = new.comandante AND vice = new.comandante), but still no go

Comment: Why don't you use check constraint? Much simpler and faster

Comment: in case you don't want to insert the new value you should return NULL, expection is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the issue myself, never mind.

This is the right trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION controllaPiloti() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (new.comandante = new.vice)
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Comandante e vice non possono coincidere!';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE TRIGGER checkPiloti
BEFORE INSERT ON viaggio FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE controllaPiloti();
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: In the case where you don't want to insert a new value, you need to return `NULL`. It's not sufficient to raise an exception alone.

Comment: In my case raising the exception also prevents the insert of the new record in the DB